# Reduce to combination of list in items of tuples

Tags: python, list, filter, tuples, combinations

I have list of tuples, I want to learn new one and I wonder how to elegantly sort out items from this list of tuples and remove all duplicates, as if duplicates (6, 1) and (1, 6) would be equal to each other. I so I'd need minimum combination.

`lst = [(1, 1), (4, 1), (1, 4), (3, 1), (1, 3), (9, 1), (1, 9), (6, 1), (1, 6), (5, 1), (1, 5)]`

I have tried:

```
res = set([tuple(sorted(list(x))) for x in lst])
```

And it works, but is some kind of spaghetti programming. Is there more elegant way?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you show the expected output?

Comment: If you want to shorten the code, I think this snippet achieves the same outcome:

    set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in lst])

Answer (score 1):

There are no "elegant" ways at times ... but the example below, reproduces the same result, but using lambda.

```
set(map(lambda element: tuple(sorted(element)), lst))

{(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 9), (1, 1)}
```